# ImportError while running tests on Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, importerror

I have a Python project that's built like this:

```
├── process_folder
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_udf.py
│   │   └── test_process.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── process.py
│   └── udf.py
```

And process.py contains `from udf import *`

Now, when I run test_udf.py, it ends successfully - but when I run test_process.py, I get this error:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: C:\Dev\Spark\process_folder\tests
test_process.py:None (test_process.py)
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Dev\Spark\process_folder\tests\test_process.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_process.py:5: in <module>
    from ..process import *
..\process.py:9: in <module>
    from udf import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'udf'
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
__________________ ERROR collecting test_process.py __________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Dev\Spark\process_folder\tests\test_process.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_process.py:5: in <module>
    from ..process import *
..\process.py:9: in <module>
    from udf import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'udf'
```

I can't understand the difference between them, and why one is working and the other doesn't (I guess it has something to do with folders, locations, and where my import comes from), I tried all kind of solutions I found online (delete `__init__.py` file for example), but didn't succeed in running the tests.

Edit - what worked for me is absolute import, process.py now contains:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "./")
from udf import *
```

And now I can run the tests locally, and the same code runs on the server without failing.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `from .udf import *`, to specify that udf is in the same dir as process

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this kind of errors completely by using absolute imports. [Pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a directory inside a package ends up on sys.path):
>
> ```py
> import mypkg.sibling
> from mypkg import sibling
> from mypkg.sibling import example
> ```

Comment: Yes, I changed the import to ```from process_folder.udf import *```, it allowed me to run the tests locally, but when I uploaded the project to the server, and tried running ```process.py``` I got this error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'process_folder.udf'; 'process_folder' is not a package```

Comment: Try `python -m process`